# Looking for a program that can track and generate delivery notes

Tags: windows, offline

As the title suggests...

I need a program that can generate delivery notes on the fly, as well as tracking delivery notes made in the past. Ideally, I don't want the program to be web-based as my internet connection isn't the most reliable, so a local install would be preferred.

A free solution would be ideal, given the circumstances.

Thanks for viewing!